# Can't convert a string into a list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, list, magic-square

I am trying to make a program in python that identifies whether a square is a magic square or not and i am having trouble getting the user input into a list. I understand that my code could be more efficient but I am very new to python.

```
column_1 = (0,3)
column_2 = (0,3)
column_3 = (0,3)
column_4 = (0,3)

row_1 = [int(i) for i in input('input row 1 with spaces inbetween numbers: ').split(' ')]
row_2 = [int(i) for i in input('input row 2 with spaces inbetween numbers: ').split(' ')]
row_3 = [int(i) for i in input('input row 3 with spaces inbetween numbers: ').split(' ')]
row_4 = [int(i) for i in input('input row 4 with spaces inbetween numbers: ').split(' ')]

column_1[0].append(row_1[0])
column_1[1].append(row_2[0])
column_1[2].append(row_3[0])
column_1[3].append(row_4[0])

column_2[0] = row_1[1]
column_2[1] = row_2[1]
column_2[2] = row_3[1]
column_2[3] = row_4[1]

column_3[0] = row_1[2]
column_3[1] = row_2[2]
column_3[2] = row_3[2]
column_3[3] = row_4[2]

column_4[0] = row_1[3]
column_4[1] = row_2[3]
column_4[2] = row_3[3]
column_4[3] = row_4[3]

diagonal_left_to_right[0] = column_1[0]
diagonal_left_to_right[1] = column_2[1]
diagonal_left_to_right[2] = column_3[2]
diagonal_left_to_right[3] = column_4[3]

diagonal_right_to_left[0] = column_4[0]
diagonal_right_to_left[1] = column_3[1]
diagonal_right_to_left[2] = column_2[2]
diagonal_right_to_left[3] = column_1[3]

sum_row_1 = sum(row_1)
sum_row_2 = sum(row_2)
sum_row_3 = sum(row_3)
sum_row_4 = sum(row_4)

sum_col_1 = sum(column_1)
sum_col_2 = sum(column_2)
sum_col_3 = sum(column_3)
sum_col_4 = sum(column_4)

sum_dag_l2r = sum(diagonal_left_to_right)
sum_dag_r2l = sum(diagonal_right_to_left)

if sum_row_1 == sum_row_2 == sum_row_3 == sum_row_4 == sum_col_1 == sum_col_2 == sum_col_3 == sum_col_4 == sum_dag_r2l == sum_dag_l2r:
    print('magic')

else:
    print('not magic')
```

I keep getting error messages that 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
I have tried a lot of different methods that I found on this website and none of them have worked for various reasons.
I am open to all suggestions, anything will help me.
Thanks

Comment: column_1 is a tuple and your trying to append something to it

Answer (score 0):

You first define `column_1` as tuple (with 2 integer values, one at index 0 and one at index 1). The `append` method cannot work on `column_1[0]`, which is like doing `0.append()`. You probably did not intend to create a tuple, but a list with certain dimensions.

You can assign the values to columns and diagonals with this list notation:

```
column_1 = [row_1[0], row_2[0], row_3[0], row_4[0]]
column_2 = [row_1[1], row_2[1], row_3[1], row_4[1]]
column_3 = [row_1[2], row_2[2], row_3[2], row_4[2]]
column_4 = [row_1[3], row_2[3], row_3[3], row_4[3]]
diagonal_left_to_right = [column_1[0],column_2[1],column_3[2],column_4[3]]
diagonal_right_to_left = [column_4[0],column_3[1],column_2[2], column_1[3]]
```